# Как сделать include поверх fragment'a?

Tags: android

Как сделать include поверх fragment'a?
В верхнем левом углу должна быть иконка "гамбургер-меню", но карта перекрыла его.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:cameraBearing="0"
        map:cameraTargetLat="1"
        map:cameraTargetLng="1"
        map:cameraTilt="30"
        map:cameraZoom="10"
        map:mapType="normal"
        map:uiCompass="false"
        map:uiRotateGestures="true"
        map:uiScrollGestures="true"
        map:uiTiltGestures="true"
        map:uiZoomControls="false"
        map:uiZoomGestures="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте местами fragment и include. В данный момент fragment у вас находится выше по оси Z и закрывает собой include.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:cameraBearing="0"
    map:cameraTargetLat="1"
    map:cameraTargetLng="1"
    map:cameraTilt="30"
    map:cameraZoom="10"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiCompass="false"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="false"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true" />

 <include
    layout="@layout/main_toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```